# How does Hyperledger Fabric perform endorsement, and who are clients in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Below is my understanding of a Hyperledger Fabric system. Do let me know if any of it is incorrect.

1) So we have peers (endorser, anchor, general (who has the ledger), orderer). Also when we setup the fabric, let's say we registered two organizations. let's call them Company A and Company B. Now what I should do is use cryptogen to generate their certificates which go to specific folder.(in crypto folder, what I'll have at this stage is keystore and signcerts for Company A and Company B).

Now for these companies, A and B, I also make the peers for them. Let's say I give peer0 (anchor) to Company A and peer1 (anchor) to Company B and also
I give peer2 (general) to Company A and peer3 (general) to Company B and also I give peer4 (endorser) to Company A and peer5 (endorser) to Company B. As my understanding each organization must have at least 1 endorser peer (who receives requests from client), at least 1 general peer (who has the ledger) and at least 1 anchor peer who gets blocks from orderer to give it to general peers in the same organization.

So this is the setup. Let's say I give these peers to company A and B and I also setup orderer peer (let's leave it as SOLO). before I run the network, I also need to have genesis block and channel. Let's create global channel and call it EveryoneChannel and put all peers in it.

---

I will go on. Now when I want to have chaincode, which node should have this written chaincode? My understanding is that chaincode must be owned by endorser, because as I read it's the one who executes chaincode to simulate proposal to return it to user. So endorsers have chaincodes? General peers have ledgers. anchors get blocks and give it to general peers in the same organization. I know what orderer does.

---

Who are the clients? I have read many times that clients make transaction requests to network. So my guess is in each organization, for example Company A, Company A can register employees that will be binded to Company A's Organization. Let's say Company A has registered three employees, employee1, employee2,employee3. so what will happen is 3 certificates will be created for these employees and they will also be saved in crypto folder.

Now what can happen is employe1 can make a transaction request to the endorser peer that is in the same organization as is employee1. employee1 already has the certificate as I mentioned so request and response and transaction will be valid. Company A's endorser will take care of it.

---

Now I also have read about endorsement policy. so it means transaction will be valid if it will be validated by n-th times of number peers from organizations and it's said that this endorsement policy is written
in chaincode. if we have Company A and Company B, and their endorsers have chaincodes, should I put endorsement policy in both of them? I guess when client makes transaction request, he can only make this request to his only organization, not other organizations. so Company A's endorser will have this chaincode and endorsement policy. so what will happen? Company'As  endorser also throws this request to Company B's endorser and waits its response and returns two responses to client?

Answer (score 2):

First, I would refer you to the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502199/what-kind-of-peer-types-does-hyperledger-have) question. It explains the different peer types, as well as linking to the relevant Hyperledger Fabric documentation. The documentation explains everything much better than I could, with some nice diagrams :)

You have the right general idea about how the network is configured and operates, but to pick up on a couple of points in your question:

- Anchor peers do not have any special responsibility for distributing blocks, they merely act as initial connection endpoints to allow other organizations to discover all other peers in the network. See [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/glossary.html#anchor-peer) for more details on how this works.
- The endorsement policy is defined when the chaincode is instantiated. If an endorsement policy requires endorsement from multiple organisations, the client initiating the transaction must send the transaction proposal to an endorsing peer for each organisation required by the endorsement policy. Once all necessary peers have returned a properly signed transaction response, these are then sent to the orderer for packaging into a block, and transmission to all peers. On receipt of a block from the orderer, each peer then performs it's own validation against the endorsement policy, before committing the block to its copy of the ledger.